# How to include rows with a count of 0

Tags: sql

I am trying to count all of the movies where actors have their roles labeled as "Uncredited". The result should include all of the actors who don't have an uncredited role but with a 0 as the count.

I have tried

---

```
SELECT COUNT(MOVIEROLE.MR_ROLE) AS "COUNT", ACTOR.A_NAME

FROM MOVIEROLE LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTOR

ON MOVIEROLE.A_ID = ACTOR.A_ID

WHERE MOVIEROLE.MR_ROLE LIKE '%UNCREDITED%'

GROUP BY ACTOR.A_NAME
```

---

This returns

---

```
COUNT | A_NAME

  3   | Chris Evans

  1   | Chris Hemsworth

  2   | Mark Ruffalo

  1   | Samuel L Jackson

  1   | Scarlett Johansson
```

---

I need something that will return the above but with this on it too

---

```
COUNT | A_NAME 

  0   | Robert Downey JR

  0   | Jeremy Renner
```

---

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep all *actors*, that should be the first table in the `left join`:

```
select a.a_name, count(mr.a_id)
from actor a left join
     movierole mr
     on mr.a_id = a.a_id and mr.role like '%UNCREDITED%'
group by a.a_name;
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't know I could add the where onto the join!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you want by changing your `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` which will keep all rows from the second ("right") table in the `JOIN` expression. Note you will need to move your `WHERE` expression to the `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(MOVIEROLE.MR_ROLE) AS "COUNT", ACTOR.A_NAME
FROM MOVIEROLE RIGHT OUTER JOIN ACTOR
ON MOVIEROLE.A_ID = ACTOR.A_ID AND MOVIEROLE.MR_ROLE LIKE '%UNCREDITED%'
GROUP BY ACTOR.A_NAME
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much and you also thought me something new!